# How to convert multidimensional array to multidimensional list in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, list, multidimensional-array, kotlin

I'm making a grid for a Scrabble game and I was trying to represent it with a 2D array so that i could fill it in easily using []. But how do i convert it to a 2D list (to get those helpful methods)?

I've tried using 2D list, but couldn't find an easy way to fill 255 indexes with cells.

```
data class Cells(

    private val cells: Array<Array<Cell>> =
            Array<Array<Cell>>(15) {
                Array<Cell>(15) { Cell(NONE, null) }
            },
    val cellslist: List<List<Cell>> = ...
) {

init {

    cells[0][0] = Cell(X3_WORD, null)
    cells[0][1] = Cell(NONE, null)
    ...
    cells[14][13] = Cell(NONE, null)
    cells[14][14] = Cell(X3_WORD, null)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To just convert it to `List<List<Cell>>`, you could just `map` it `toList`:

```
cells.map(Array<Cell>::toList)
```

But this has the downside of making a deep copy. To have the result mutable with the arrays on the JVM, you could wrap these with `java.util.Arrays.asList()`:

```
cells.map { Arrays.asList(*it) }
```